# Are there any other sites other than Onelook that search multiple dictionaries simultaneously?

Tags: discussion

Somebody said I should try Onelook but whatever I search in there, including the word *hello* or *book* (see picture below), nothing seems to work.

Are there other sites like Onelook?

[image: Screenshot of OneLook's null result for "book"]

Comment: I get the same null result for a search for the word "book", while all other words work fine. On another machine, the onelook search for the word "book" works fine. That make me think that the link to a png file in that post may be a malicious one.  I suggest that other users not click on it.

Comment: I found that the null search result for "book" was confined to firefox (not a problem in Chrome), and the only way to fix it was to delete and reinstall firefox. The post above, and its malicious link, should be removed

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty It's a simple screenshot, but it's now hosted on imgur.

Comment: [Firefox works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQWiM.png) so it's likely to be a browser problem which is preventing OneLook working for Rai. That doesn't preclude an answer which suggests an alternative, though.

Answer (score 2):

What URL are you using to access OneLook? Which browser? Do you have any ad-blocking software enabled? Are you using a VPN or connecting through a firewall? [Looking up 'book' in OneLook](https://onelook.com/?w=book&ls=a) `(https://onelook.com/?w=book&ls=a)` works perfectly for me even with almost all of my browser's privacy protections enabled. You may have malware in your browser, or some privacy protection you have enabled is preventing the site from working properly. You may want to contact the developers of OneLook to get their help or let them know about the problem. There is a form at the bottom of [their help page](https://onelook.com/about.shtml).

> [image: My search of OnLook showing "book" in the search box with other suggested terms in a drop-down box and many results from different dictionaries.]

I don't know of another site as comprehensive as OneLook.